# copy as and mv as not behaving as expected when using nnn terminal file manager

Tags: terminal, file-manager

I'm using the nnn file manager v3.2 on Mint 19.3 64-bit. If I have a file named ‘a.txt’ and I want to make a copy of it named ‘b.txt’ in the same directory, I do the following: I select ‘a.txt’ so that it has a + prefixed to it’s name, press ‘w’ and then press ‘c’ to copy (as). However, after pressing ‘c’, instead of being asked to input a new name (‘b.txt’) my text editor gvim is launched and I get a cp error message in nnn’s terminal stating that "‘a.txt’ can’t be copied to ‘a.txt’". Have I misinterpreted the procedure, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

The workflow for cp/mv is to open the paths in selection in your $VISUAL (else $EDITOR) and let you edit them (because if you have selected 20 files it doesn't make sense to ask and rename one by one).

Your $VISUAL/$EDITOR is set to gvim so the list is opener in gvim. Rename the entries as you want and **save** the file for the changes to apply.

In your case you haven't renamed the entry a.txt before saving the file so the error message is shown. You can't have 2 files with the same same in a directory.

Note: If you want to use a cli editor like vim, set $VISUAL ($EDITOR if you do not want to set $VISUAL) to vim an duse the program option `-e`.

Comment: The cp error message appears before the editor opens. cp: '/home/standard_user/a.txt' and '/home/standard_user/a.txt' are the same file ‘, Enter' to continue. The editor then opens a ‘.nnn…...’ file in /tmp. The first line is: #/home/standard_user/a.txt and the scond line is: a.txt. If a.txt on the second line is changed to b.txt and the file is saved, b.txt is not saved to the home dir.

Comment: I think the gvim is opened detached so the program does not wait for it. Please fix that. If it still doesn't work, please raise a defect in the project page so the devs can take a look at it.